# An equality of trace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, operator-theory, operator-algebras

Is the following equality is true for trace?

$\mathrm{Re}\bigl(\operatorname{Tr}(-YZ^*X+YXZ^*)\bigr)=\mathrm{Re} \bigl(\operatorname{Tr}(XYZ-YXZ)\bigr)$ for complex matrices $X,Y,Z.$

Actually I am trying to show that with respect to certain inner product on the Lie algebra of a linear connected semisimple Lie group $-\mathrm{ad}(X^*)=(\mathrm{ad}X)^*$.

Comment: It is easy to sample a counterexample. Are you sure you have written down the conjecture correctly?

Comment: No! I just noticed that I have made a mistake and I have solved the original problem.

Comment: About your second question. It seems like to be a really interesting question, however, I cannot understand what do you mean by  $\mathrm{ad}(X^∗)=(\mathrm{ad}X)^∗$. If $X\in \mathfrak{g}$ what does $X^*$ means? Are you seeing $\mathfrak g\subset \mathfrak{gl}(\mathbb C, n )$ (by Ado's theorem)?